# Scala Why does the List class define a toList Method?

Tags: scala

The scala docs define the following method in class List:

```
def toList: List[A]
```

As far as I can tell this method just returns a copy of our initial list.
[image: toList method]

What is the use case of this method?

Comment: It's on every other stdlib collection, why shouldn't it be on this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider something like this:

```
def bar(strings: List[String]) = strings.foreach(println)
def foo(ints: Seq[Int]) = bar(int.map(_.toString).toList)

foo(List(1,2,3))
foo(1 to 3)
foo(Stream.from(1).take(3))
```

etc.

`foo` accepts a `Seq` of ints, converts them to strings, and calls `bar`, that wants a `List`.

You can send any kind of `Seq` to `foo`, and it uses `.toList` to convert it to a `List` before invoking `bar`, because that's the only type it will accept. Now, if the argument to `foo` happens to already be `List` (like in the first example above), it will end up calling `List.toList`, which is just a nicer, more elegant alternative to making a special case in the code to check the concrete type of the argument.

Answer (score 5):

`List` extends the `GenTraversableOnce` trait, which is a common trait for many other traversable collections.

`GenTraversableOnce` [declares](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html#toList:List[A]) a `toList` method so that all subclasses can be converted into a `List`. This method *must* be implemented by `List` (and indeed - trivially by returning `this`).

Comment: So we never have a situation where we will actually want to call this method?

Comment: If you _know_ the collection you have at hand is a `List` - then no, there's no real use for it; But you might have a variable of type `GenTraversableOnce` which _might_ or _might not_ be a `List` (you don't know the actual implementation), or a concrete type that is not a list which extends `GenTraversableOnce` (e.g. `Array`) - and then using `toList` might be useful. I've actually seen it used / used it myself quite often.